# Remove an element from the DOM based on a variable reference to it?

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically creating a `div` like this:

```
var gameScoreDiv= document.createElement('div');
gameScoreDiv.innerHTML= 'Score: 0';
wrapperDiv.appendChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

Later I need to remove this `div` from DOM. How can I get rid of that `div`?

Is it possible to simply delete the `gameScoreDiv` variable and have it remove also the `DOM` element (I have a feeling the answer is no)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2019 update**

You can remove node with [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) now:

```
gameScoreDiv.remove()
```

It's supported by every major browser with the not surprising exception of IE (for which you can add a tiny polyfill though, if needed).

---

You can do:

```
gameScoreDiv.parentNode.removeChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

or, if you still have reference to the `wrapperDiv`:

```
wrapperDiv.removeChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

In jQuery it would be:

```
$(gameScoreDiv).remove();
```

but this will use the `parentNode` way, see [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a5037cb9e3851b171b49f6d717fb40e59aa344c2/src/manipulation.js#L355).

Comment: I'm avoiding jQuery for this project but your plain javascript solution worked nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) method.

In your case I see that `wrapperDiv` is the parent element, so simply call it on that:

```
wrapperDiv.removeChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

Alternatively, in another scope where that isn't available, use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) to find the parent:

```
gameScoreDiv.parentNode.removeChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give your dynamically created div an id, and later you can see if any element with this id exists, delete it. i.e.

```
    var gameScoreDiv= document.createElement('div');
    gameScoreDiv.setAttribute("id","divGameScore");
    gameScoreDiv.innerHTML= 'Score: 0';
    wrapperDiv.appendChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

and later:

```
    var gameScoreDiv= document.getElementById('divGameScore');
     wrapperDiv.removeChild(gameScoreDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
gameScoreDiv.id = "someID";

//Remove the div like this:
var element = document.getElementById('someID');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```